# Create a new site using Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-artisan

I am a newbie to Laravel. I have just created an old site using Laravel homestead. Is there anyway to create another new site, instead of overriding the previous site?

Answer (score 0):

In your Homestead folder ist a `Homestead.yaml` file. There you have some config data. In your case you should have something like this:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
nfs: true


authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/yourname/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: first-site.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/first-site/public
```

just add two more lines underneath your first-site lines.
Then it should look like this:

```
sites:
    - map: first-site.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/first-site/public
    - map: second-site.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/second-site/public
```

Also add the following line to your .hosts file: `127.0.0.1 second-site.app`

Now you have to provision your vagrant box with the command `vagrant provision`